# how to return guid from a class in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a way I can return a Guid with the code below? For example, what I'm passing in to AddSchedule is a class. I want to return an Id from the class so I can so something with it in the controller. How would I change my code to resolve this?

**Controller**

```
ModelService.AddSchedule(
                new Schedule
                {
                 Id = Guid.Empty,
                 Start = start,
                 Stop = end
                });
```

**What I want to do with the return Guid**

```
 ModelService.AddScheduleToPerson(
                new Schedule
                {
                 Id = ?,   // get this from above
                 UserId = userid,
                 User = username
                });
```

**Model**

```
public ObjectCreateStatus AddSchedule(Schedule schedule)
    {
        var client = new Services.ConfigurationClient();
        try
        {
            ConfigurationMessage cMsg =
                client.ConfigService.AddSchedule(
                    this.ControllerBase.SessionVariables.Credentials,
                    schedule
                    );
            if (cMsg.Result == ConfigurationResultEnum.Success)
                return ObjectCreateStatus.Success;                
            return ObjectCreateStatus.GeneralError;
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: return a Guid from what exactly?

Comment: Considering your edit, if you would like AddSchedule to return a Guid where is that Guid generated? Does the ConfigurationMessage returned by `client.ConfigService.AddSchedule()` have that data? Changing the return type of your method is as simple as changing the signature and updating the return statement to return the value which you desire. `public Guid AddSchedule(Schedule schedule) { /*...*/ return Guid.NewGuid(); }`, but that alone obviously isn't going to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to return a GUID as well as an ObjectCreateStatus you could consider using an out parameter for it.

```
 public ObjectCreateStatus AddSchedule(Schedule schedule, out Guid guid) { }
```

Comment: I am not a fan of out parameters in general. I feel that it is a cover up of code smell. If you need to return two disparate values from a function that function probably is doing too much. Not saying never use them. But in this case refactoring the code in question might be a better option.

Comment: It really depends on the circumstance, but generally I agree. `Type.TryParse()` is a good example of a valid use of the out parameter.

Comment: @ Nathan Tylor and Everyone -- what I specify above, how do I get the return Guid ... I mean instead of returning "ObjectCreateStatus", I want to return the "Guid".

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a wrapper object that can contain both your `ObjectCreateStatus` and your `Guid` and return that. Something like this:

```
public class ObjectCreateResult
{
    public ObjectCreateStatus CreateStatus { get; set; }
    public Guid CreateGuid { get; set; }
}


public ObjectCreateResult AddSchedule(Schedule schedule)
{
    ObjectCreateResult result = new ObjectCreateResult();

    var client = new Services.ConfigurationClient();
    try
    {
        ConfigurationMessage cMsg =
            client.ConfigService.AddSchedule(
                this.ControllerBase.SessionVariables.Credentials,
                schedule
                );
        if (cMsg.Result == ConfigurationResultEnum.Success)
        {
            result.CreateStatus = ObjectCreateStatus.Success;
            result.CreateGuid = Guid.NewGuid(); // Set your actual Guid here
        }
        else
        {
            result.CreateStatus = ObjectCreateStatus.GeneralError;
            result.CreateGuid = Guid.Empty;
        }

    }
    finally
    {
        client.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `out` parameter.  I'm assigning the GUID at the beginning of the method, but you may want to change that logic depending on your requirements.  Here's your modified code:

```
public ObjectCreateStatus AddSchedule(Schedule schedule, out Guid theGuid)
    {
        theGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var client = new Services.ConfigurationClient();
        try
        {
            ConfigurationMessage cMsg =
                client.ConfigService.AddSchedule(
                    this.ControllerBase.SessionVariables.Credentials,
                    schedule
                    );
            if (cMsg.Result == ConfigurationResultEnum.Success)
                return ObjectCreateStatus.Success;                
            return ObjectCreateStatus.GeneralError;
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider making the `ObjectCreateStatus` a class:

```
public class ObjectCreateStatus {
  public bool WasSuccessful { get; private set; }
  public Guid ScheduleId { get; private set; }

  ctor(ConfigurationResultEnum result, Guid guid) {
    WasSuccessful = result == ConfigurationResultEnum.Success;
    ScheduleId = guid
  }
}

public ObjectCreateStatus AddSchedule(Schedule schedule)
{
    var client = new Services.ConfigurationClient();
    try
    {
        ConfigurationMessage cMsg =
            client.ConfigService.AddSchedule(
                this.ControllerBase.SessionVariables.Credentials,
                schedule
                );
        return new ObjectCreateStatus(cMsg.Result, cMsg.Guid(?))
    }
    finally
    {
        client.Close();
    }
}
```